# How does the entropy diffusivity changes with radius in the Sun?

Tags: the-sun, astrophysics, stellar-astrophysics, sunspots, entropy

Could you please explain - How does the entropy diffusivity changes with radius in the Sun?

As far I know, In the convection zone, the entropy diffusivity increases as the temperature and density decrease further.

But I am not able to find a graph that shows relationship between entropy diffusivity and radius of the sun. Could you please let me know if you are aware of any such graph?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer your question, but I do have luminosity data from the Standard Solar Model (BP2004), courtesy of John N. Bahcall, on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/212e9a8cc73c203a93d288606ac4e466). There's a simple demo in Sage / Python in a comment below the data.